# How to get Windows recommended display scaling?

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

via this can get current display scaling

```
var dpiRatio = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
```

but, I need **recommended** display scaling

[image]

Is it possible to get this value?

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This setting is the screen DPI, or dots per inch.

```
Read it like so:
float dpiX, dpiY;
Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
dpiX = graphics.DpiX;
dpiY = graphics.DpiY;
```

I don't think it's possible at the moment for the X and Y values to be different. A value of 96 corresponds to 100% font scaling (smaller), 120 corresponds to 125% scaling (medium) and 144 corresponds to 150% scaling (larger). However, users are able to set values other than these standard ones.

Answer (score 0):

In the current state of the new Windows 8/10 System Configuration Window. Not all settings are accessible via an API.

Here u can find information in general about DPI scaling [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx)

But for ur current question - 'Recommended' is just a calculation in between the physical monitor resolution, it's dpi and the OS dpi. I wasn't able to find the actual calculation but maybe ur able to find it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
ResolutionScale resolutionScale DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ResolutionScale;
double factor = (double)resolutionScale / 100.0;
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226165

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand.